# Potentially Uninitialized Local Pointer Variable - Alternatives?

Tags: c++, linked-list

The following code is part of my implementation for a class member function that rents lockers and thus creates nodes in a linked list:

```
void SelfStorageList::rentLocker(Locker e) {

int count = 0;
LockerNode *p = head;

if (isEmpty()) {
    head = new LockerNode(e, head);
    tail = head;
}

LockerNode *prev = head;
LockerNode *curr = head->next;

for( ; curr != 0 && curr->objLocker.isVip; prev = prev->next, curr = curr->next) {

    if(count == 1) {

        if (e.isVip) {

           if(p->objLocker.isVip)  {
           LockerNode *p = new LockerNode(e, p->next);

           }
           else {
           LockerNode *p = new LockerNode(e,head);
           }

        }

    //etc...
```

When I run it, I get two errors that my *p pointers may potentially be uninitialized. I don't think they would pose any sort of run time error issues, but the program will not compile as long as the errors persist. I was wondering what alternative I might have to the current implementation of the

```
LockerNode *p = new LockerNode(e, p->next);
```

and

```
LockerNode *p = new LockerNode(e,head);
```

lines. All I want them to do is to create new nodes with the passed in info element of e, either before the current listed locker or after, depending on the condition.

Thanks for any help provided! Let me know if it would be useful to post any other particular parts of the code, although it is quite lengthy, so I was hoping to avoid posting it all and isolating the problem into a manageable module.

Comment: May be it is better to move `p` to outer scope and use `LockerNode p = 0` (before `for` statement).

Comment: You have different variables called `p` in different scopes. Try fixing that first, then the errors might become clearer.

Answer (score 4):

In this `if-else`, you are declaring a new pointer `p` in each block:

```
if(p->objLocker.isVip)  {
   LockerNode *p = new LockerNode(e, p->next);
 }
 else {
   LockerNode *p = new LockerNode(e,head);
 }
```

Each one of these is local to the scope. It results in a memory leak, and has no effect on the `p` from the outer scope.

Comment: Ahh, whoops. They are an artifact from a previous attempt. Am I correct, then, in that if I replace "LockerNode *p" with just "p", that I will affect the outer p, and remove the leak/error concerns?